# How to reconstruct non-pointer class member containing vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor, segmentation-fault

I'm facing a weird issue : I can't reset (destruct and construct) properly an attribute containing a vector. It causes a segmentation fault when trying to access the vector.

Here is my code (witten in C++11). I think I simplified it the most possible to underscore the issue, but I might be wrong, sorry about that.
The goal would be to print two times two different (random) vectors. The first vector is working well, the second is completely failing for an unknown reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

class A
{
        std::vector<int> n;

    public :
        A();
        std::string toString() const;
};

A::A()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        n.push_back(std::rand()%10);
}

std::string A::toString() const
{
    for (auto i : n)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

class B
{
        A a;

    public :
        void resetA();
        A getA() const;
};

void B::resetA()
{
    a = A();
}

A B::getA() const
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    B b;
    std::cout << b.getA().toString();
    b.resetA();
    std::cout << b.getA().toString();


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For some reason, I would like to avoid pointers and dynamic allocation as far as possible. It would fit less with my UML conception.

Moreover, this code is working well when using simple int (no vectors).

Thank you.

Comment: @Cyber std::vector does not need to be resized. push_back dynamically grows the vector. In fact, resize would make his vector 20 items long with 10 uninitialized values at the beginning. You mean to say reserve but that is also wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `toString()` doesn't return anything, so your program has Undefined Behaviour (and, in practice, returns random garbage which is most certainly not a valid `std::string` object).

Perhaps you wanted to use a string stream instead?

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::string A::toString() const
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    for (auto i : n)
        s << i << ' ';
    s << '\n';
    return s.str();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/3e2nf8).

Generally, it's a good idea to compile with as many warnings turned on as possible. This would certainly have been reported as a warning then. For this particular warning (no-`void` function not returning anything), I strongly suggest treating it as an error.

Comment: You are right, this solves the problem described. My mistake.
However, the issue in the non-simplified program unfortunately comes from elswhere. Thank you.